# How to test the build on particular version of HHVM in travis-ci?

Tags: php, travis-ci, hhvm

I am trying to test my laravel project on hhvm in travis. I couldn't find a way to specify a particular version of hhvm in .travis.yml. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Version specific HHVM specification in Travis-CI was added by my request with this issue https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/pull/733 at the end of May 2016

Note: it's Limited to LTS versions of HHVM because of how HHVM supplies versions.

You can see how to do the HHVM version specification in the documentation now https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php#HHVM-versions

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to download the .deb file from the [repository](http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hhvm/) and install it as part of your script using `dpkg -i`. To do so, you require being able to run `sudo` as `dpkg -i` has to be run as root.

While doing this, remember that most Travis tests are run on Ubuntu 12.04, which only gets up to HHVM-3.6. You'll need to opt into the trusty beta to be able to run newer versions.